# How to restrict a database in postgresql from multiple user

Tags: postgresql

I created a PostgreSQL database in a publicly visible server.

There are several users, but I want only 2-3 of them can access the database in the system. All should be able to read and write data.

So how can I restrict the other user? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

By default the right to *connect* to a database is granted to the `public` role.

So the first thing you need to do is to revoke that. To do that log in  to that database as the superuser (typically `postgres`), e.g.

```
psql -U postgres new_database
```

Then at the SQL prompt run:

```
revoke connect on database new_database from public;
```

Then you need to grant the privilege to each user:

```
grant connect on database new_database to user_1;
grant connect on database new_database to user_2;
```

Replace `new_database` with the name of the database you created.

You can also control the access to the server through `pg_hba.conf` but that is a bit more complicated. For details see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html